# How do I add jpg files to a Delphi project for BitMap.CreateFromFile?

Tags: delphi, bitmap, msbuild

I am using Dephi RAD Studio XE5 and creating a Firemonkey project that needs to run on android, ios, and win32.

I am trying to load a bitmap using BitMap.CreateFromFile(). I've added an 'images' folder to the project and stored the images in that folder. I've also added the images to the project so that they appear in the Project Manager view.

The problem is that when I try to use

```
TBitmap.CreateFromFile('images/myimage.jpg')
```

my app on win32 gives me the following error message:

Cannot open file "C:...\Win32\Debug\images\myimage.jpg"

Which suggests that the build process isn't copying the image files into the Debug folder.

How do I convince the build process to copy the images folder into the Debug folder?

edit:

Yes, I understand that computers aren't mind readers. :) Notwithstanding, when eclipse (for example) encounters a file in its src directory that it doesn't recognize as source code (like a .jpg or .xml) it will happily copy the file into the corresponding location in the bin directory. The underlying assumption is that the dev knows what they are doing. That's all I am looking for here.

I could use resources, but I don't like the idea of compiling images into my executable. Eventually, I'll want to change the images, perhaps having the app download additional images from a URL and caching them in the images directory. Who knows? Compiling images into an executable feels like closing the options box for future expansion.

Answer (score 1):

The build process won't copy your images files to the output folder. It is not capable of reading your mind!

If you want the files to be copied during the build then you'll need to add a pre-build or post-build event to perform the copy. The event might look like this:

```
xcopy /iy "$(PROJECTDIR)\images" "$(OUTPUTDIR)"images
```

---

As an aside, I think using `TBitmap.CreateFromFile('images/myimage.jpg')` is asking for trouble. That code assumes that the process working directory contains the images directory. That may be true, but is not guaranteed. If you wish to search for these files relative to the executable directory, you should build the full path yourself, starting from `ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))`. And personally, unless you have other reasons for deploying these assets as files, compiling them into your program as resources would be preferable. It makes deployment of your application simpler.

Comment: Close! This solution works on Win32 but not on Android. I'm guessing I need to convince Delphi to add entries to the AndroidManifest.xml file. Presumably something similar but different for iOS.

Comment: Fair point. I know nothing about deployment on mobile. You'd really be better off embedding as resources I think.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi does not do that for you automatically. You have several options though:

- Copy the images to your output folder manually. Delphi will leave them untouched during the build.
- Embed the images in your executable as resources. Then you don't have to provide the images when installing your application.
- Use a build server such as Jenkins or FinalBuild to do the build for you. These tools are very flexible and allow you to do a lot more than just copying resource files in the right folder.